# How to transfer the data from attribute table to Excel sheet in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I want to automatically write the data from the attribute table of the layer I have created to an Excel sheet. Is there a script for that?

[image]

Comment: Please include data like these as a formatted table rather than a screenshot. It makes it much easier for someone to help  you if they can quickly reproduce your data by copy-pasting. [See how to do it here](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/#:~:text=Table,%7C%20Paragraph%20%7C%20Text%20%7C).

Answer (score 3):

If it's only one layer execute [Convert format](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#gdalconvertformat) manually. But if you want to use pyqgis:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("my_sample")[0] #Change "my_sample to the name of your layer"
output = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/my_sample.xlsx" #Change
processing.run("gdal:convertformat", 
    {'INPUT':layer,'CONVERT_ALL_LAYERS':False,'OPTIONS':'','OUTPUT':output})
```